# Selenium IE WebDriver cannot see any windows

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium WebDriver to navigate through a series of pages and eventually it gets to a point where the page is redirected to an external payment page. It is the existing window which is redirected, not a new window opened however if I try to interact with any objects after the redirection I get the exception `Unable to find element on closed window`. The page requires a login so I cannot provide a link for you to use.

I did some debugging and found that at the point of the payment page, `driver.WindowHandles` returns an empty collection and `driver.CurrentWindowHandle` will throw a NoSuchWindowException.

I am using IE 8 and WebDriver 2.44.0.0 32-bit. I have played around with the recommended IE settings but haven't found anything to help. Does anyone know why my WebDriver is losing it's handles?

Note that this works fine with Chrome and Firefox drivers.

Example:

```
public void Test()
{
    var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(site);
    var check1 = driver.WindowHandles;  // 1 window exists here
    driver.FindElement(elementA).Click();
    System.Sleep(10000);
    var check2 = driver.WindowHandles;  // 0 windows exist here
    driver.FindElement(elementB).Click();
}
```

Comment: You should use explicit wait till your element get visible then only selenium will be able to find it. if you share your code then can help you better.

Comment: Hi helping hands, I have an explicit wait of 10 seconds (the page loads in < 1 second) to make sure the it is there but no deal. The code doesn't help because it is literally just 2 clicks, the first works, the second doesn't... I will add the example anyway

Comment: Yes, works fine in Chrome and Firefox... it is definitely an issue with IEWebDriver or my IE settings. I cannot even attempt to find any elements, because I lose my window handle! =(

Comment: Where you instantiate the `browser `? I really had hard time understanding the flow of your code. Is that completed?

Comment: Sorry, browser == driver. Missed that when renaming it for this example... not the cause of the issue I'm having however.